# Android app keeps crashing in AVD, but is built properly in Gradle

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I made this small android app with two buttons and a textview, pretty basic. But its not starting in the emulator. No build errors whatsoever.

Here's the activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/toast_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/toast_text"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:onClick="showToast"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_counter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="370dp"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:text="@string/counter_initial_value"
    android:textSize="160sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/count_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:text="@string/count"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:onClick="counterUp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here's the MainActivity.java file

```
package com.example.android.testapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final TextView mShowCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_counter);
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toast_button);
private int mCount = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


public void showToast(View view) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, 
R.string.toast_popup,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}

public void counterUp(View view) {
    mCount++;
    if(mShowCounter != null) {
        mShowCounter.setText(Integer.toString(mCount));
    }
}
}
```

I've tried making multiple projects, but this is not working. In the first project, it started showing an error after the first build saying "cannot resolve symbol R", highlighting all instances of R in red. However, in this build there have been no errors still the app has not started even once in the emulator.

Comment: To check the caused due to your app crashed you may refer to check Logcat into your IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access `**xml**` instances before it get's created that's makes app causing to crashed.

To check the caused due to your app crashed you may refer to check **`Logcat`** into your IDE.

Put Your instantiation code inside `onCreate()` callback:-

```
package com.example.android.testapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final TextView mShowCounter;
final Button button;
private int mCount = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mShowCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_counter);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toast_button);
}


public void showToast(View view) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, 
R.string.toast_popup,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}

public void counterUp(View view) {
    mCount++;
    if(mShowCounter != null) {
        mShowCounter.setText(Integer.toString(mCount));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: thank you so much @MrRoshan for helping me in this question!

Comment: Welcome boss..!!

Answer (score 3):

> Android app keeps crashing in AVD, but is built properly in Gradle

Because you are doing **`findViewById`** outside `onCreate()` without doing **`setContentView()`**

Do **`findViewById`** inside `onCreate()` method after **`setContentView()`**

Declare your `TextView mShowCounter` and `Button button;` as Global

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 TextView mShowCounter ;
 Button button  ;
private int mCount = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     mShowCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_counter);
     button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toast_button);
}


public void showToast(View view) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, 
R.string.toast_popup,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}

public void counterUp(View view) {
    mCount++;
    if(mShowCounter != null) {
        mShowCounter.setText(Integer.toString(mCount));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @AqibAhmed declare your `mShowCounter` as global like my answer it will work

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for the instant help you gave. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @AqibAhmed happy to help you

Comment: @NileshRathod he has no privilege yet.but I have..!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in these lines.

```
final TextView mShowCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_counter);
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toast_button);
```

Your app crashes because during the class init phase, the Views don't exist yet. `findViewById` will not work.

You should instead move these lines inside `onCreate`.

Answer (score 2):

Your component initializations should go in the `onCreate()` i.e put your

```
mShowCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_counter);
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toast_button);
```

inside of `onCreate()`.